# How to filter JPA repository?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to filter JPA repository

```
@RequestMapping("/search")
    public String search(@ModelAttribute Person search, Model model) {
        PersonSpecifications spec = new PersonSpecifications();
        model.addAttribute("people", this.hotelRepository.findAll(spec.lastNameIsLike("Foo")));
        return "people/list";
    }
```

And got the following error

```
The method findAll(Iterable<Long>) in the type CrudRepository<Person,Long> is not applicable for the arguments (Specification<Person>)
```

Please advise. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use `Specification`s you need to make your repository extend `JpaSpecificationExecutor`.